# Refresh input to change value ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form that is dynamic and display inputs (select, multiple or text) when an answer is provided on previous question.

When a text input is created, it is because of the answer of the previous question, which means that many way can be created by answering differently.

The problem :

When I answer a select question, for example, a text input can be displayed next. If I answer this input, another input can be displayed. But, if I update my answer for the first select input, this means that a new way is created, but the next one is still a text input, so ReactJS don't create a new one, just update the existing one. The fact is that the value is still in the input, and that's not what I want, I need the value to be updated, either by a defined value, or by an empty one, but this need to be updated.

I have created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-unijv3) example with a little reproduction.

In this reproduction, you can choose a value in the select input, but then if you choose the other one, the value will not be updated on the input. The only way to update it, is to clear it and recreate it by choosing a new value.

I know that in this example, using the value from the state and updating the state directly in the change method will work, but in my project I don't have a defined number of text inputs.

The only thing I see to do it with state, is to create an array and dynamically adding or removing values when inputs are added or removed from the form. But I would prefer a "refresh" input method.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your selected values inside Array state then loop map the

```
//states
            
this.state = {
   values: []
};

//joinin new values with previous array
handleSelect(event) {
    var joined = this.state.values.concat(event.target.value);
    this.setState({ values: joined });
}
    
//then mapping on render
<div>
    {
       this.state.values.map(x=>(
         <Input value={x} placeholder="type here" />
       ))
    }
 </div>
```

Here is working example in your code:https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-n1jbk6

Comment: Yes that's the only solution I see for now as I wrote on my post, but I would prefer a solution that update the element instead if it's possible.